# Generate P2SH bitcoin address from WIF in BitcoinJ Java

Tags: java, bitcoin, bitcoinj

I'm trying to create P2SH-Segwit bitcoin address from the WIF private key. I'm using the **BitcoinJ library in Java**. See the following code.

```
String base58PrivateKeyString = "KyyJ5vVWjZck5nsAgDWvoN1u7Q8qp5FzE8WiCq97MbnRgdLesqJZ";

NetworkParameters params = MainNetParams.get();
ECKey key;

if (base58PrivateKeyString.length() == 51 || base58PrivateKeyString.length() == 52) {
    DumpedPrivateKey dumpedPrivateKey = DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(params, base58PrivateKeyString);
    key = dumpedPrivateKey.getKey();
} else {
    BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(base58PrivateKeyString);
    key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privKey);
}

// Getting the public key
String pubKeyStr = key.getPublicKeyAsHex();
System.out.println("Public key is: " + pubKeyStr + "\n");

// Getting the P2SH address
List<ECKey> eckeyAList = new ArrayList<>();
eckeyAList.add(key);
Script redeemScript = ScriptBuilder.createRedeemScript(1, eckeyAList);
Script script = ScriptBuilder.createP2SHOutputScript(redeemScript);
byte[] scriptHash = ScriptPattern.extractHashFromP2SH(script);
LegacyAddress legacyAddress = LegacyAddress.fromScriptHash(params, scriptHash);
System.out.println("P2S address from the WIF pivate key is: " + legacyAddress.toString()); //3Az5wdibtPRGac41aGtyqzT1ejtobvb6qW
```

Its output public key is 03b5319c83adf4a2e274c37401623c7bf0ba453cee3e119f3bc2c523d27059b64f.
Its **output P2SH address is 3Az5wdibtPRGac41aGtyqzT1ejtobvb6qW** which is far different from the **correct P2SH address 38SGXvkMvq8Tsop8rFx2K4JnaFKYZkjd5z**.

If any of you know to rectifying the issue I'm happy to take your opinion.

Comment: Please share if you found a way

Comment: I found the way. See the answer marked as the correct ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending very much of time I found the solution.

```
// Getting P2SH address
LegacyAddress p2shAddressObj = LegacyAddress.fromScriptHash(PARAMS,
                                Utils.sha256hash160(ScriptBuilder
                                .createP2WPKHOutputScript(key.getPubKeyHash())
                                .getProgram())); // P2WPKH-P2SH (3* segwit compatible)
String p2shAddress = p2shAddressObj.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

As a Redeem Script you must use P2WPKH (Pay to Witness Public Key Hash)
And then the creation of the Redeem Script will look like:

Script redeemScript = ScriptBuilder.createP2WPKHOutputScript(key);

Comment: Is there a way to generate P2SH-P2WSH segwit address? like this one: bc1qwfgdjyy95aay2686fn74h6a4nu9eev6np7q4fn204dkj3274frlqrskvx0

Comment: They are long than normal segwit addresses.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Bitcoinj has a method in SegwitAddress.class for this:

Comment: `public static SegwitAddress fromKey(NetworkParameters params, ECKey key) { 
 checkArgument(key.isCompressed(), "only compressed keys allowed"); return fromHash(params, key.getPubKeyHash()); 
}`

Comment: I mean like [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5261325.msg54778139#msg54778139)

Comment: Are those 62 character long can be generated this way?

Comment: bc1q5shngj24323nsrmxv99st02na6srekfctt30ch vs
bc1qt4h06ssqtwncv5rtf8c8v53emwmvr9j5peq9quj9vf0jzu2egnxqpesxny

Answer (score -1):

This is the right code by using Mikhail's suggestion in kotlin:

```
val params: NetworkParameters = MainNetParams.get()
val key: ECKey = ECKey.fromPrivate(BigInteger("2"))
val redeemScript: Script = ScriptBuilder.createP2WPKHOutputScript(key)
val script = ScriptBuilder.createP2SHOutputScript(redeemScript)
val scriptHash = ScriptPattern.extractHashFromP2SH(script)
val legacyAddress = LegacyAddress.fromScriptHash(params, scriptHash)
println("P2S address from the WIF private key is: $legacyAddress")
```